# Is there a way to read one line and the next one, iterating over a .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, csv, intellij-idea, bufferedreader

I would like to read one line of a .txt file using BufferReader. But my question is that I need to read one line and the next one together, and then go to the next line and do it again with its next one. Here is an exemple :

```
A
B
C
D
```

I need to read A and B (and process), then B and C (process), then C and D.

Do I need to create an array to store each pair and then process? Or can I process when iterating over the file? I'm currently doing this :

```java
while (file = in.readLine() != null) {
            String[] data = file.split(",");
            String source = data[0];
            file = in.readLine();
            String destination = data[0];        
        }
```

Here the goal is to put the previous destination as the next source.
But then when my while loop goes on the next line, don't I skip one letter?

Thanks for your attention !

Comment: Well. After reading A and B, you do not need to read B again. You already have it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I edited a bit my message because it wasn't totally clear, sorry !

Comment: Why don't you step through your code with a debugger and see what it's doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
        String a = in.readLine();
        if (a == null) {
            return;
        }
       
        for (String b; (b = in.readLine()) != null; a = b) {
            // do smth
            
        }
```

Maybe the reduce operation of the Stream pipeline is also helpful for you. For example, if you want to concatinate all lines together:

```
   Optional<String> reduce = in.lines().reduce("", (a,b) -> a+b);
   if (reduce.isPresent()) {
     // ..
   } else {
     // ...
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'm working with csv files so I don't think I can concatenate all of them which would make it impossible to read. However using a for loop looks good. I didn't know we could put a = b as next step.

Comment: Well, you can always use a while loop instead of a for loop.  The concatination in my stream was just an example, you can use any binary function there. I don't know what exactly you want to do with both lines but you could try to use reduce with that.

Comment: I'm creating a graph on which I put the first line as source and the next line as target. I need to check if each pair of lines are connections I need for my graph  (checking an other column of the csv file), because some pairs have to be avoided in my graph. I'm sorry if it's a bit misty but I don't want people to completely solve my issues so I don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two element `String` array as a "buffer".

```java
String[] buffer = new String[2];
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("path-to-your-file");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        if (buffer[0] == null) {
            buffer[0] = line;
        }
        else if (buffer[1] == null) {
            buffer[1] = line;
        }
        else {
            // Do whatever to the contents of 'buffer'
            buffer[0] = buffer[1];
            buffer[1] = line;
        }
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    // Do whatever to the contents of 'buffer'
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
```

When you exit the `while` loop, you have not processed the last two lines of the file, hence you need to perform the processing one last time after exiting the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Working with String[] could be good especially since I'm working with csv files. However I need to work on many files in the same time and having to manually compute the last lines is not very convenient.